# regular expression for "one token appears multiple times"

Tags: regex

From MSDN, seen from the explanation of "[CString::Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)",

The call will fail if the string object itself is offered as a parameter to Format. Following is an example:

```
CString str = "Some Data";
str.Format("%s%d", str, 123);   // Attention: str is also used in the parameter list.
```

Now I want to check whether there are codes in my project went against this rule.

I think regular expression can help me achieve this goal. (I mean the regular expression that is usually built in Editor's search/find file function, not the regular expression used in C#/C++/Java/Python etc)

In short, the expression might look like this:

```
XXX.Format\(.*XXX.*\)
```

where the XXX can vary to be a valid variable name. E.g. "str", "sql_string", "_mystr"

Note: I can download any editor like Notepad++, sublime text; I have visual studio. So it is quite ok if you can solve this issue on any editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression like below should do the job (with `\1` to reference the first capture group - your variable):

```
^\s*(.+?)\.Format\(.*\1.*\)
```

There are a few assumptions and things to note though:

- I assumed that the variable is the first thing in the line, proceeded by whitespace only.
- The variable is only checked to appear in brackets after `.Format` (as you put it in your question). The same variable may appear in the first parameter, the regex currently doesn't check that.
- You may add additional whitespace to the regex if neeeded.